# When building OData queries for ADO Test Plans, is it possible to establish a reference relationship between TestPoints and TestResults?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

Essentially, I'd like to be able to gather some fields from `TestResults` associated with the specific `TestCaseWorkItems` but cannot seem to find any confirmation on whether this is currently doable with the OData v4.0 preview.

My specific query is being built for Power BI reporting on ADO Test Plans, and I'd like to pull back a list of `TestRuns` associated with `TestCases` belonging to `TestSuites` residing in a particular ADO `AreaPath`, along with a number of field values.

From the MS docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/entity-reference-test-plans?view=azure-devops), I'm seeing that the following list of objects can be used to establish a relationship with one another:

- `TestSuites`
- `TestConfiguration`
- `TestPoints`
- `TestCaseWorkItem`

While `TestPoints` do have fields like `LastResultOutcome`, multiple Tests can be run for the same `TestPoint`, and each Test has its own timestamp, outcome, and run details that I can't seem to use in reference to the `TestCase` they belong to. There is a second list of objects that all relate to each other, but I cannot find how they relate back to the `TestSuite`/`TestPoint` hierarchy. They are:

- `TestResults`
- `TestRuns`
- `Tests`
- `Pipelines`
- `PipelineRuns`

In the ADO interface, double-clicking a `TestPoint`'s `TestCase` will open an execution history for that test case which shows that there is some way these `TestCase` items are able to logically reference their runs, however so far I've found no field that successfully can be used.

Test items do have a `TestCaseReferenceId` field, however this field does not match either the `TestCaseId` in `TestPoints` or the `WorkItemId` for the `TestCaseWorkItem`. From the reference, this field is apparently the test case number, and not the ID.

My query currently looks like this:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v4.0-preview/TestPoints? 
    $apply=filter(TestSuite/TestPlanWorkItem/Area/AreaPath eq '{areapath}') 
    &$select= 
        LastResultState,LastResultOutcome,ChangedDate,AnalyticsUpdatedDate, 
        TestPlanId,TestSuiteId,TestPointId,TestCaseId,Priority,AutomationStatus 
    &$expand=
        TestSuite( 
            $select= 
                TestPlanTitle,Title, 
                IdLevel1,TitleLevel1,IdLevel2,TitleLevel2, 
                IdLevel3,TitleLevel3,IdLevel4,TitleLevel4, 
                IdLevel5,TitleLevel5,Depth;
            $expand=TestPlanWorkItem($expand=Area($select=AreaPath))), 
        AssignedTo($select=UserName), 
        Tester($select=UserName), 
        TestCase(
            $select= 
                WorkItemId,InProgressDate,CompletedDate, 
                Revision,Title,WorkItemType,ChangedDate, 
                CreatedDate,State,Reason,ClosedDate,ResolvedDate, 
                Priority,StateCategory,StateChangeDate; 
            $expand= 
                ChangedBy($select=UserName), 
                ActivatedBy($select=UserName), 
                ClosedBy($select=Username), 
                ResolvedBy($select=Username)
                )
```

Is there a way to relate this to TestResults that I'm missing?

Comment: have you figured out the solution? I'm trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: @007 hey, it's been a minute since I was working on this, so my memory may not be exact on the outcome, but I believe the conclusion I reached was that OData queries specifically aren't equipped to set up this relationship, at least not within the scope of a single query (though I may be mistaken). There may be some Rest API or pipelines capacity with ADO that'd be worth pursuing if it's absolutely necessary, but I believe in my case, we just contented ourself with the last test case outcome and moved on.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I explored the REST API option but we've come to the same conclusion as you. Hopefully they'll improve this in the future to make things easier for PBI users.